# httpd 2.4 returning forbidden message when using alias

Tags: permissions, apache-http-server, alias, httpd

As a part of displaying a live log file, I managed to setup and deploy an httpd server on fedora 19.  For accessing the log files that are outside the **www** folder, I created aliases, so that when **test** is appended to the address, the **test** folder in the alias is referred to. I followed the [official manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias)
and the the aliases are properly configured to my best knowledge.

When I try to access a file outside the **www** folder, the browser returns

[image: Error Message]

I made two sample folders named **testvar** inside & outside **www** for testing. If the alias is referring the **testvar** folder inside **www**, the content is delivered, but not if it is referring to the outside folder. I hope that explains that the syntax is error free, and that this is some kind of permission error.

**Current configuration (httpd.conf)**

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Listen 80
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf`

User apache
Group apache

ServerAdmin root@localhost

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require local
    Require all granted
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    Require local
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require local
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    Alias /test "/var/testvar"
    Alias /test2 "/var/www/testvar"
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>

<Directory "/var/testvar">
    AllowOverride None
    Options All
    Require local
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/testvar">
    AllowOverride None
    Options All
    Require local
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require local
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
  MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

EnableSendfile on

IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

What should I do to make the folders outside the **www** folder accessible to my project? Since my end goal would be to access the httpd log, would this approach be good enough?

Comment: Everytime a change is made to the configuration file, the service has been restarted to make sure it is reloaded. Even if I do not add a trailing slash to the url, it is automatically corrected to /test/, on both browsers I used to test this. I've already tried all the possible combinations of adding and removing the trailing slash in both the config file and the url, to no avail.

Comment: The user and group, both are currently set as apache (as you can see from the configuration), as it is not advised to set them as root.